# What would you like to ask the Stack Exchange Community Team?

Tags: discussion

As you may or may not know, Stack Exchange moderators have access to a Private Team SE site where staff and mods can discuss stuff and help each other (similar to Meta Stack Exchange, but with restricted access).

Today a discussion opened there inviting questions from mods for the CM (community manager) team. Here is the most important part of the post:

> The CM/Mod Quarterly Meetup is your opportunity to ask questions that matter to you personally or folks from the communities you moderate. You can ask any question about the Stack Exchange network, even if the answer requires us (CMs) to contact our colleagues in other departments. We can't promise that we will answer every question, but we will do our best to bring the information that interests you.

If there is anything you would like to be raised, please post about it here before 16th November.